# How to remove texts after some sentences?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with n rows that contain some text. Some of these rows contain extra text that I would like to remove and the extra text happens to show up after some specific sentences.

Let me take an example:

```
df = structure(list(Text = c("The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.", 
"The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.", "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now ready to take your questions. Life is great even if it is too hot to work at the moment.", 
"The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.", "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.", 
"The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now at your disposal for questions. I really need to remove this bit that comes after since I don't need it. Hopefully SE will sort this out.", 
"The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.", "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.", 
"The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.", "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. Transcript of the questions asked and the answers. Summertime is nice.", 
"The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.", "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I would like to get:

```
#                                                               Text
# 1                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
# 2                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
# 3            The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now ready to take your questions.
# 4                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
# 5                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
# 6          The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now at your disposal for questions.
# 7                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
# 8                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
# 9                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
# 10 The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. Transcript of the questions asked and the answers.
# 11                                                    The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
# 12                                                    The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
```

The dataframe is a simplified representation of the real one. The extra text (which is always the same in the example but it varies in the real one) comes *always* after the three sentences: *We are now at your disposal for questions.*, *Transcript of the questions asked and the answers.* and *We are now ready to take your questions.*

Can anyone help me sort this out?

You would really make my day.

Thanks!

Comment: Does my answer work for you? Hope that I don't misunderstand anything.

Comment: @DarrenTsai yes it works I just need to iterate it 3 times with different text at the beginnig. Thanks:)

Comment: Why does it need iteration? You said the extra texts always come after some sentences. You just need to put these sentences into a vector (i.e. `patvec`) and run my code. Anyway glad to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
df$Text <- sub("I really need to remove .*", "", df$Text)
```

We could create a pattern vector and use a `for` loop

```
patvec <- c("We are now at your disposal for questions.", 
    "Transcript of the questions asked and the answers.", 
  "We are now ready to take your questions.",
  "I really need to remove this bit that comes after since I don't need it.")

# // loop over the sequence of pattern vector
for(i in seq_along(patvec)) {
     # // create a regex pattern to capture the strings
     # // including the pattern vector elements
     tmppat <- paste0("^(.*", patvec[i], ").*")
     # // use sub with replacement on the captured group i.e. string inside (..)
     # // assign and update the column Text
     df$Text <- sub(tmppat, "\\1", df$Text)
  }
```

-output

```
df
                                                                                                      #Text
#1                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
#2                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
#3            The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now ready to take your questions.
#4                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
#5                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
#6          The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now at your disposal for questions.
#7                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
#8                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
#9                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
#10 The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. Transcript of the questions asked and the answers.
#11                                                    The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
#12                                                    The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
```

NOTE: This should work fine even if there are hundreds of thousands of pattern vector elements

Comment: What if *I really need to remove* changes row by row? I don't have it fixed. It varies a lot after those 3 sentences.

Comment: @Rollo99 It does change the whole column row by row

Comment: @Rollo99 The expected output seems to be matching with the `sub` output

Comment: I made a few changes to make the df close to my case. Have a look at it now please

Comment: @Rollo99 I am just trying to understand the common patterns after your change.  What would be the common patterns after which you want to remove the text

Comment: in my real df, the extra texts always come after these 3 sentences: We are now at your disposal for questions. / Transcript of the questions asked and the answers./ We are now ready to take your questions.

Comment: I can just repeat your code 3 times and the problem is solve

Comment: Really impressive master! You really made my day!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  distinct(Text) %>% 
  mutate(Text = str_replace_all(Text, regex("I really need to .*"), ""))
df2
# Text
# 1                                                     The text you see here is fine, no problem with this.
# 2           The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now ready to take your questions. 
# 3         The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now at your disposal for questions. 
# 4 The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. Transcript of the questions asked and the answers.
```

Comment: Thanks but we have the same problem as below. "I really need to" is not constant in my df. I changed the df to make it more similar to my case. Plase have a look at it

Comment: same as below, I could just repeat your code below 3 times and the problem is sorted

Answer (score 1):

You can use the syntax `"(?<=a|b|c)text"` in regular expressions to match what you want to remove.

```
patvec <- c("We are now at your disposal for questions.", 
            "Transcript of the questions asked and the answers.", 
            "We are now ready to take your questions.",
            "I really need to remove this bit that comes after since I don't need it.")

regex <- sprintf("(?<=%s).*", paste(patvec, collapse = "|"))
sub(regex, "", df$Text, perl = T)

#  [1] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."                                                   
#  [2] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."                                                   
#  [3] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now ready to take your questions."          
#  [4] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."                                                   
#  [5] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."                                                   
#  [6] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. We are now at your disposal for questions."        
#  [7] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."                                                   
#  [8] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."                                                   
#  [9] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."                                                   
# [10] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this. Transcript of the questions asked and the answers."
# [11] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."                                                   
# [12] "The text you see here is fine, no problem with this."
```